# mmap to PCI bar fails in SUSE

Tags: linux, mmap, opensuse, pci, sles

I am trying to do mmap to PCI CSR bar. mmap fails with error EINVAL. Below is my code snippet.

```
snprintf(csr_bar_path,256,"/sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:16:00.0/resource2");
csr_fd = open(csr_bar_path,O_RDWR | O_SYNC);
if(csr_fd < 0)
{
    printf("Cannot open CSR bar file %s\n",csr_bar_path);
}
if(fstat(csr_fd,&sb) == -1)
{
    printf("CSR file size = %d\n",sb.st_size);
    close(csr_fd);
}
printf("CSR file size OK = %d\n",sb.st_size);
csr_bar = (unsigned char *)mmap(NULL,sb.st_size,PROT_READ | 
                                  PROT_WRITE,MAP_SHARED,csr_fd,0);
if(csr_bar == (void *) -1)
{
    printf("mmap failed for CSR bar %s %d\n",strerror(errno),errno);
    close(csr_fd);
}
```

The value obtained for sb.st_size is 65536. But mmap failed with error string "Invalid argument". The same code snippet works fine in RHEL 7.2 but fails in SLES15 operating system.

Comment: Can anybody please provide an update on this query?